# How to run docker service with volume with multiple replicas

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nexus, docker-swarm

In my docker swarm cluster, I am running nexus3 repository as docker image registry. This repository is a critical component of my devops infrastructure, because we have many jenkins instances running in the swarm thar start all their build in separate build agent containers. When my nexus service is down, my jenkins instances can not pull the images for the build agent containers and so they are not able to start builds anymore, if nexus crashes (for example because the cluster node  which is running nexus crashes or is rebooted).

Yesterday we had the additional problem, that the node, nexus was running on, was the only node that had a local copy of the image for nexus itself. So no other host could launch my nexus service. I had to rebuild my image from the GIT repository with the Dockerfile on another node and then launch nexus there. All in all, this took about half an hour in which we were not able do start any build job.

So I tried to start nexus in replicated mode with two replicas, like this:

```
deploy:
  mode: replicated
  replicas: 2
```

My nexus service is using a volume like this:

```
services:
  nexus:
    volumes:
      - sonatype-work:/opt/sonatype/sonatype-work
[...]
volumes:
  sonatype-work:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      o: bind
      device: /mnt/docker-data/services/nexus3/sonatype-work
      type: none
```

When I redeploy my nexus stack, one instance is starting and the second one always starts and  then exits without error (completed). See `docker service ps` for my nexus service:

```
docker@master:/mnt/docker-data/services/nexus3$ docker service ps nexus_nexus
ID             NAME                IMAGE                                NODE   DESIRED STATE  CURRENT STATE           ERROR   PORTS
oxez5kl866ma   nexus_nexus.1       localhost:5001/devops/nexus3:0.0.1   node1  Running        Running 2 minutes ago
u0s6slqlj0uf   nexus_nexus.2       localhost:5001/devops/nexus3:0.0.1   node4  Ready          Ready 1 second ago
d1u1btefzf1s    \_ nexus_nexus.2   localhost:5001/devops/nexus3:0.0.1   node4  Shutdown       Complete 1 second ago
ythgbtrmycon    \_ nexus_nexus.2   localhost:5001/devops/nexus3:0.0.1   node3  Shutdown       Complete 8 seconds ago
```

The log (`docker service logs -f nexus_nexus`) gives no information why my second instance does not stay running but always completes and restarts. 
Is there maybe an I/O conflict, because both instances try to use a volume on the node they are deployed on that points  to the same host directory (see `device` in my volume definition)?
Or does someone have another idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: [HA on nexus3](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/high-availability) is only available through the commercial license (Pro version) and is not exactly setup through a simple sharing of a data directory. You cannot run two instances of nexus3 on the same shared data directory. At best it will not function at all, at worse... get ready to take your backups out because there is a very high risk you bump into a major data corruption.

Comment: @Zeitounator: Thank you. I think you are right with "...it will not function at all...", because my second instance is always shutting down directly after startup. I reset to 1 replica now and I will have to check for another solution.